# How do we set color to an underline for text in textView programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android. I created a table and set `textView` inside it .I would like to give underline to the text I input in `textView`. I created an underline by the following code :

`SpannableString content=new SpannableString(Regions)
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),0,Regions.length(),0);`

where region is the string containing text.

Can anyone tell me how do we set a color based on our choice to the underline?

Comment: same way you can use Spannable

Comment: No..it didn't work in my code.. I found an alternate way to do the project without using underline in textview to save time.

Comment: No. I Used alternative background color for each row and created a textview outside the table as a hint stating to click on the row to view more details. The purpose of underline was to make the user know it was a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, there is no straight way to do it. You can check my solution below :

Modify the text view as below in your layout :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/residential_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/only_one_bottom_line"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:text="test string"
            android:textColor="@drawable/re_option_highlight"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
```

only_one_bottom_line.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-4dp" android:right="-4dp" android:left="-4dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#0093dd" >
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

> This background have only one bottom line, and you can change the color from #00 93dd to any color you want. This solution is more easier to implement than creating a custom text view and making hell lot of changes there.

Answer (score -1):

To give color to perticuler string you can use Spannable

```
String s="your text";
    SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(s);                
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, 5, 0);  
    tv.setText(ss);
```

Comment: what exactly your requirement